# error with factorial.m function, getting non negative matrix error

Tags: matlab

I have the following vector, 
N=10
vec=-N:1:N

and when running the command

`factorial((N+vec)/2))`

I am getting the error

> ??? Error using ==> factorial at 17
>   N must be a matrix of non-negative integers.

when "(N+vec)/2" is just

```
ans =
     0    0.5000    1.0000    1.5000    2.0000    2.5000    3.0000    3.5000    4.0000
4.5000    5.0000    5.5000    6.0000    6.5000    7.0000    7.5000    8.0000    8.5000
9.0000    9.5000   10.0000
```

no negative numbers...

any trick to get around it?

thank you!

Comment: From your error: factorial at 17 N must be a matrix of non-negative **integers**. Those are not integers.

Comment: sh!t! cant beleive ive missed it. thank!

Answer (score 0):

As wakjah stated in his comment, your problem is that when you divide by 2 in performing `(N+vec)/2`, you're getting non-integral numbers. You can do something like

```
factorial(round((N+vec)/2))
```

to round your `factorial` input values to their nearest integer values. Other rounding alternatives are `floor` to round down, and `ceil` to round up